# Detect if user tapped the screen, including Buttons, in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I've been trying to use .onTapGesture to detect if the user taps on the screen. However, I noticed that it doesn't get triggered if the user taps on actionable elements like buttons and pickers. Is there a way to detect if the user taps on the screen, including these actionable elements without having to manually call my `viewTapped` function for each button, picker, etc. separately?

Here's the code I used to test this.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var mode = 0
        
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .padding()
                
                Picker(
                    selection: $mode,
                    label: Text("Picker")) {
                    Text("Option 1").tag(0)
                    Text("Option 2").tag(1)
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .frame(width: 200)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                
                Button {
                    print("button clicked")
                } label: {
                    Text("Click me")
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.green)
        .onTapGesture {
            viewTapped()
        }
    }
    
    public func viewTapped() {
        print("view tapped")
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want both `button clicked` and `view tapped` printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to detect touches **simultaneity**, you need the `simultaneousGesture` modifier instead. like:

```
.simultaneousGesture(
    TapGesture()
        .onEnded {
            viewTapped()
        }
)
```